# Как проверить есть ли цифра в числе?

Tags: python

У меня есть число 1940859530992 и я хочу проверить есть ли в нем число 0,и если есть,то выполнить какие-то действия.Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: if '0' in '1940859530992':

Comment: Если просто скопировать заголовок в гугл и ещё добавить слово python, то в результатах поиска сразу же [на второй ссылке](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2450055.html) будет готовое решение

Answer (score 1):

Цифра в отличии от числа это символ. Проверяй преобразовав число к симолам.

```
'0' in str(1940859530992)
```